# Login panel with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to code a login box (panel) like this:[Look at right top 'subscribe'](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/build-a-top-panel-with-jquery/)

I want a panel like this with a different. It must open with jquery (or another library) slide. I tried something but when I left the first div (I gave link :'subscribe' div-ol-)
It hide. I hope I explain my problem.. In other words, I want to do a login box with hover event and effect.

Comment: "wanna" is not a word, please stop using it.

Comment: Including some of your code so far in the question would go a long way toward explaining your problem better.

Comment: I am sorry. I am not an English or an American so I can make mistakes..

Comment: The example in the link has a hover event and is coded in jQuery.

Comment: but, I want to add effect to hover event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here for a simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/D3AP2/

Relevant code:

```
   $('#container').hover(function(){
        $('.hid').slideToggle();
    });
```

You just set the .hover() on the containing element, in my example the `<ul>` instead of the link. That prevents it from closing, when you leave the link to go down to the other options.

Comment: Oh sir, thanks a lot. I want this for my page. So thank you :)